# Check cache size of wired tiger in a mongodb

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

I try to set a limit on the cache size of wiredTiger in a mongodb.
First of all, I executed the following command:

```
mongod --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 1
```

I also added the following lines to the configuration file named mongod.conf.orig

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
  wiredTiger:
    engineConfig:
       cacheSizeGB: 1
```

and then executed the command:

```
mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

To double check my change, I would like to display the currently used cache size of wired tiger.

Is there a possibility to display it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Login to the database (Atlas or on-prem) and run:

```
db.serverStatus().wiredTiger.cache
```

there's a status variable called `"bytes currently in the cache"`

There's also `"maximum bytes configured"` which should reflect your cache size.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for.